# Angular2 incorrect height of Div returned

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular2/4 and trying to get the height of a div on when a component loads

```
<div id="top"  #divId>
</div>

@ViewChild('divId') myDiv: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.myDiv.nativeElement.offsetHeight)
  }
```

But the returned height, only when the div first loads, is incorrect when I check it in the console

Any pointers?

Comment: Have you tried `ngAfterViewInit` hook? Does `div` contain images?

Comment: Wow, just tried it and worked! Thanks, if you want, you can answer the question so I can mark as correct...Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would wait until `ngAfterViewInit` hook is called

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.myDiv.nativeElement.offsetHeight)
}
```

See more information about lifecycle hooks in documentation

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: This should work but doesn't for me, please could you look at my question on this?